# How do I deal with output files when using argparse?

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

I have a program and I want to make it so that if the user specifies the exact name of the 2 output files given, then those files will be named at the user's preference.

For ex:

```
-o file1.txt file2.txt
```

If the output files aren't specified then the script will automatically generate the files with default names.

Comment: Could you show what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the argparse module, which provides clean ways of handling input arguments. For your task, you can use something like

```
arguments = argparse.ArgumentParser()
arguments.add_argument('fileNames', nargs='*', help='Output file names', default = ['val1', 'val2'])
inputArgs = arguments.parse_args()

# User may decide to give just one file name
outFileName1 = inputArgs.fileNames[0]
outFileName2 = 'val2' if len(inputArgs.fileNames) == 1 else inputArgs.fileNames[1]
```